# Call fetchgit without SSL Verify

Tags: ssl, nix

I'm trying to use `fetchgit` to download source repos from my lab's private GitLab server, which currently self-signs its SSL certificate.

`default.nix`:

```
with (import <nixpkgs> {});
{ test-pkg = callPackage ./test-pkg.nix {
    buildPythonPackage = python35Packages.buildPythonPackage;
    };
}
```

`test-pkg.nix`:

```
{ buildPythonPackage,fetchgit }:

buildPythonPackage rec {
  pname = "test-pkg";
  version = "0.2.1";

  src = fetchgit {
    url = "https://gitlabserver/experiment-deployment/test-pkg";
    rev = "refs/tags/v${version}";
    sha256 = "43c2c9e5e7a16b6c88ba3088a9bfc82f7db8e13378be7c78d6c14a5f8ed05afd";
  };
}
```

Which results in the error when I call `nix-shell`

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlabserver/experiment-deployment/test-pkg/': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
```

Looking at, [build-support/fetchgit](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/build-support/fetchgit/default.nix), it seems that `fetchgit` is made with `mkDerivation`, so I tried to make a new `fetchgit` using `overrideAttrs`. I pass in the git environment variable to make git ignore SSL verification, expecting that the variable will be initialized during the setup phase.

revised `default.nix`:

```
with (import <nixpkgs> {});
let fetchgit-no-verify = fetchgit.overrideAttrs { GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true;} ;
in rec {
  test-pkg = callPackage ./test-pkg.nix {
    buildPythonPackage = python35Packages.buildPythonPackage;
    fetchgit = fetchgit-no-verify;
    };
}
```

I thought I was really clever when I thought of this over the weekend, only to discover that when implemented my new error states that

```
error: attribute 'overrideAttrs' missing, at [...]/default.nix:2:26
```

Inspecting `fetchgit` in `nix repl` shows that it is a `functor` attribute set. I tried for a little bit to get to the `overrideAttrs`, without success. Trying again I saw that `git` could be passed to to `fetchGit`,

re-revised `default.nix`:

```
with (import <nixpkgs> {});
let git = git.overrideAttrs { GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true;} ;
    fetchgit-no-verify = fetchgit.override { git=git-no-verify;} ;
in rec {
  test-pkg = callPackage ./test-pkg.nix {
    buildPythonPackage = python35Packages.buildPythonPackage;
    fetchgit = fetchgit-no-verify;
    };
}
```

but the new error:

```
 error: attempt to call something which is not a function but a set, at /nix/store/jmynn33vcn3mcscsch0zf46fz9wsw05y-nixpkgs-20.03pre193309.c4196cca9ac/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:318:55
```

Finally, onto my questions. Is there a way to add the environment variable to the `fetchgit` or `git` derivations? Is there perhaps another way to connect--some builtin option I missed? I could use a private repository, using ssh and avoiding https, however due to how we deploy experiments I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make this work with this ugly thing.

`default.nix`:

```
with (import <nixpkgs> {});
let fetchgit-no-verify = fetchgit // {
  __functor = self : args :
      (fetchgit.__functor self args).overrideAttrs (oldAttrs:{GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true;});
  } ;
in rec {
  test-pkg = callPackage ./test-pkg.nix {
    buildPythonPackage = python35Packages.buildPythonPackage;
    fetchgit = fetchgit-no-verify;
    };
}
```

`fetchgit-no-verify` uses the `fetchgit` functor set to begin with and overwrites the `__functor` attribute with a new function. The new functor just applies its arguments and then calls `overrideAttrs`.

This works, but I'm happy to award the answer to anybody who can add some insight or comes with another solution. For one, I'd like to know how the `fetchgit` derivation becomes a functor. Is this something `callPackage` does?.